# How do I know if a specific twitter user is online or not?

Tags: twitter

How do I know if a specific twitter user is currently online by writing programs? Is there any API or data field in the web page showing this information? Both browsing Twitter webpage and using Twitter app are considered "online".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this information is not readily available, you can do a work around. Make use of Twitter's Streaming API: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/streams/public (have a read through this document).

You'll most likely be using the `POST Statuses/filter` functionality (read the doc here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/filter ), which will give you a JSON object with tweets based on your filters.

Make use of the parameters you'll need to specify in the URL to filter the stream (have a look through this document to learn more about it: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters ), in your case it'll be the `follow` parameter. You basically specify the twitter ID of the user you want to follow. Here's a sample JSON result of the streaming API in action https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?follow=25365536 - this one in particular is following Kim Kardashian. Keep in mind that this will give you:

- Tweets created by the user.
- Tweets which are retweeted by the user.
- Replies to any Tweet created by the user.
- Retweets of any Tweet created by the user.

So in order to just stream the tweets of your desired user, you'll have to use a programming language of your choice to parse through the JSON object to find the `user` that actually sent the tweet (this is a little tricky, you'll have to look through the properties of the JSON object to figure it out). Once you narrow the streaming tweets to just the ones from the user though, you can then have an alert on when new tweets by this user stream and that will tell you if the user is online/using twitter at the moment.

Comment: Hi Suvi, thank you very much for your detailed answer. I am not sure if I understand it correctly. It seems that this approach can only tell me the user status when she post a new tweet. Is it possible to sample her status at any arbitrary time? Because it is possible that one user visit Twitter's website without posting anything.

Comment: You're right, this method is only helpful to alert you when the user is actively posting - realtime, and because it is realtime you know that the user is currently "online". But as far as monitoring when someone's on the twitter webpage itself just looking at tweets, I'm not sure you can get that kind of information. I'm sure twitter has some kind of analytic tool they use internally for statistics, but they most certainly will not make it available for public use - in respect to people's privacy I would assume.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you mean by "online" (browsing twitter.com? Using a Twitter app?), but in any case Twitter doesn't provide such information, thankfully.

Comment: It's not possible in either case.

Comment: Thank you, I will try dev.twitter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid such information is limited by Twitter and is not available. However you can put your question on https://dev.twitter.com/discussions and ask its developers. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

- you need get user state first
- then filter if around current time
- then get ids
- they are online
- use twitter developer api
- I do it for my website